# imresize turns images purple

Tags: python, scipy

after using `imread` to read in an image and then using `imresize` some of my images end up becoming 100% purple and the actual image gets lost.

```
image = imread('../assets/signatures/Alex/train/' + file_name,flatten=True)
image = self.normalize(image)

  def normalize(self, image):
    image = imresize(image, (128,128))
    # Here is where the image turns purple
    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.show()
    image = np.ndarray.flatten(image, order='C')
    return image
```

Is there a reason why `imresize` does that? Maybe a dimension issue? All images have different dimensions to begin with.

I also want to mention that this error is thrown whenever the wrong image ouput is being produced:

```
C:\Users\alexh\Anaconda3\envs\Labs_Env\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\pilutil.py:97: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in float_scalars
  cscale = cmax ** cmin
C:\Users\alexh\Anaconda3\envs\Labs_Env\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\pilutil.py:104: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in power
  bytedata = (data ** cmin) * scale + low
C:\Users\alexh\Anaconda3\envs\Labs_Env\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\pilutil.py:104: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
  bytedata = (data ** cmin) * scale + low
```

originial image / After resizing:
[image]

[image]

Comment: By default, matplotlib uses viridis colormap for displaying gray images. Add cmap="gray" to plt.imshow(image). e.g. plt.imshow(image, cmap="gray". Sorry answering on my phone can't format text properly.

Comment: I have tried that and the result is the same, except that the images that were purple before are now all black.

Comment: Sorry, I wish I had a python interpreter to help you. Maybe you edit your answer to include the image you are reading with scipy.

Comment: Good idea, all done^^

Comment: Could you precise which packages are you using ? `imread` exists in `scipy.misc.imread` or in `matplotlib.pyplot.imread`, same thing with resize.

Comment: Using `matplotlib.pyplot.imread` to read the image and `scipy.misc.imresize`, I can't reproduce your problem, on two different types of images (32-bits PNG and 8-bits PNG). The warnings you have printed at the end of your question are probably the reason why you have this issue. 
Can you print the maximal/minimal values of the image before you normalize it, as well as the type of the pixels ?